# Trying to count if row is different than the previous one

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
> head(pre, 50)
         Date                Time Axis1 Axis2 Axis3     VM Standing Stepping Cycling New_Sitting
1  2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:00     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
2  2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:01     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
3  2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:02     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
4  2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:03     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
5  2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:04     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
6  2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:05     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
7  2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:06     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
8  2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:07     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
9  2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:08     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
10 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:09     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
11 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:10     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
12 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:11     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
13 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:12     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
14 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:13     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
15 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:14     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
16 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:15     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
17 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:16     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
18 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:17     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
19 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:18     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
20 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:19     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
21 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:20     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
22 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:21     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
23 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:22     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
24 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:23     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
25 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:24     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
26 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:25     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
27 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:26     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
28 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:27     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
29 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:28     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
30 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:29     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
31 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:30     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
32 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:31   105    65    14 124.28        0        0       1           0
33 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:32    34    42     1  54.05        0        0       1           0
34 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:33    98    15    54 112.89        0        0       1           0
35 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:34    81    15    19  84.54        0        0       1           0
36 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:35    69   108    93 158.35        0        0       1           0
37 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:36    44    87    98 138.24        0        1       0           0
38 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:37    36    89   209 230.00        0        0       1           0
39 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:38    70    90    40 120.83        0        0       1           0
40 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:39    75   119    48 148.63        0        0       1           0
41 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:40    33    92    14  98.74        0        0       1           0
42 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:41    34    21    19  44.25        0        0       1           0
43 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:42    16    11    40  44.46        0        1       0           0
44 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:43     0     0    22  22.00        1        0       0           0
45 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:44     6    17    14  22.83        1        0       0           0
46 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:45    10    59    36  69.84        0        0       1           0
47 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:46     0    40    47  61.72        0        0       1           0
48 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:47     0    28     8  29.12        0        0       0           1
49 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:48    84    30   116 146.33        0        0       1           0
50 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 15:46:49    53    46    17  72.21        0        0       1           0
```

The last 4 columns (Standing, Stepping, Cycling, New_Sitting) will always have 1 of them as "1" and the rest as "0". I need to be able to count how often the "1" changes position between those 4 columns. (To know how often the person changes posture).

EDIT

I'm at this step here, where I sum up the data of each column, but I still need to count how many times the posture changes (the changes in the last 4 columns)

```
Summary_PRE <- workday_PRE %>% group_by(Date) %>% mutate_if(is.character,as.numeric) %>% summarise(across(Axis1:New_Sitting,sum))
Summary_PRE <- subset (Summary_PRE, select = -c(Axis1,Axis2,Axis3,VM))
```

EDIT

With this data sample. the code should show "7" since the "1" in the last 4 columns changed places 7 times

Answer (score 1):

I've gone ahead and changed your data a little, to make it more variable

```
df=structure(list(Date = c("2022-03-17", "2022-03-17", "2022-03-17", 
"2022-03-17", "2022-03-17", "2022-03-17"), Time = c("2022-03-17 11:29:00", 
"2022-03-17 11:29:00", "2022-03-17 11:29:00", "2022-03-17 11:29:00", 
"2022-03-17 11:29:00", "2022-03-17 11:29:00"), Axis1 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Axis2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Axis3 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), VM = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Standing = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Stepping = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Cycling = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), New_Sitting = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

the code

```
rle(
  max.col(
    df[,c("Standing","Stepping","Cycling","New_Sitting")]==1
  )
)

Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:5] 1 1 1 1 2
  values : int [1:5] 4 3 2 4 1
```

the answer is 5 times.

**Edit:** given your new data, and the additional info that we should group by date (I think) you could do

```
by(
  pre,
  list(pre$Date),
  function(x){
    tmp=max.col(pre[,c("Standing","Stepping","Cycling","New_Sitting")])
    pmax(length(rle(tmp)$lengths)-1,0)
  }
)
```

resulting in

```
: 2022-03-08
[1] 8
```

8 changes (not 7, as you mention).

Comment: Is there a need for `==1` ?

Comment: @GKi No not really.

Comment: My issue with this is that I have upwards of 50000 rows of data

Comment: This only seems to work for that specific table, but I need to work for X amount of rows (1 row per second, most of the day)

Comment: @RichardMichaudLangis what do you mean by `This only seems to work for that specific table`? What is the issue? This should work for 50k rows.

Comment: Well the Date and Time values you use in the first block only include the first few seconds of data that is collected every second of the span of a week or two

Comment: @RichardMichaudLangis Are you saying that you need to group by date/time and calculate the runs within this groups separately? If so, by what aggregation?

Comment: Well I'm already grouping by date, as shown in my code above. Now I need to use that grouped data (same date, different time stamps) to count when the last 4 columns are different

Comment: @RichardMichaudLangis I don't understand. If this data you posted is not representative of your actual data then post your actual data, or a bigger sample, with your desired output.